# Sending Headers with Lighthouse

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, audit, lighthouse

I am using [Lighthouse](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse) from command line to audit my website.

In order to access my website from Chrome, I need to send custom headers (Using Modify Headers Extension).

However, when I am launching `lighthouse` from command line:

```
lighthouse http://x.y.z.a:888
```

It opens a new Chrome window (which has no Modify Headers Extension) and thus requests are sent without headers, without which the website is not accessible and hence not auditable.

Any suggestions as to how to send custom headers with `lighthouse` using command line?

Comment: I found on github,issues for solving these.


https://github.com/fdn/lighthouse/commit/16b4a45b5680512ffe403b5b632a4740ad03c4c4#diff-80fb163f1715ab174c002a5113e6ca4d

Pls. checkin the code,check if it works,and do comment!.

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible. Upvote [GoogleChrome/lighthouse#2746](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/2746) to request the feature.

Aside: The CLI has a flag called [`chrome-flags`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/blob/master/lighthouse-cli/cli-flags.ts#L74) which lets you pass in Chrome flags to LH. I was curious if there's a workaround there, but there's not. The full list of Chrome flags is described in [List of Chromium Command Line Switches](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/).